# Null reference error when adding picturebox dynamically to tabpage

Tags: c#, bitmap

Getting the exception message:

> Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.

My code is:

```
PictureBox myPicBox = new PictureBox();
myPicBox.Visible = true;
myPicBox.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\1341596825343s1jpg.jpg");
myPicBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.MyTabPage.Controls.Add(myPicBox);
```

Where `MyTabPage` is the fourth page in a tab control. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Stack Trace is Here

> at ShipSiegeDashBoard.Form1.LoadSpaceStations() in
>   C:\ShipSiegeTool\ShipSiegeDashBoard\Form1.cs:line 46    at
>   ShipSiegeDashBoard.Form1..ctor() in
>   C:\ShipSiegeTool\ShipSiegeDashBoard\Form1.cs:line 31    at
>   ShipSiegeDashBoard.Program.Main() in
>   C:\ShipSiegeTool\ShipSiegeDashBoard\Program.cs:line 18    at
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
>   args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: Have you tried debugging it and narrowing it down to which line your exception comes from? You could even try posting your stack trace which would help as well.

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: It seems like you are getting a nullpointer exeption. Add a breakpoint to your code and check which variable is not set. It could be either your tabpage or it's controls.

Comment: I did, error is coming from the add control line

Comment: Is your code placed in Form's constructor before `InitializeComponent`?

Comment: It is after the InitializeComponent in the constructor

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line throwing the exception and hover your mouse pointer over the different parts of the statement. You will see what is `null`.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your `MyTabPage` control isn't initialized yet. You should not try to use until after it has been initialized.

Comment: so I can add it to the form successfully, but not the tab page